# How to send an Integer to a TCP server in Golang?

Tags: go, tcp

I have the following client and server in Go:

Client:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
)

func main() {

var num1 int
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

fmt.Scanln(&num1)

fmt.Printf("I'm the client, your input was the number: %d", num1)

//escribir el numero a b, el buffer
err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, num1)

//Llama al server
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:9000")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

//Escribe buffer a la conexion
buf.WriteTo(conn)

//Cierra la conexión
defer conn.Close()

//Lee la conexión  y la imprime
bs, _ := io.ReadAll(conn)
fmt.Println(string(bs))
}
```

Server:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
)

func main() {
//Escuchar un request
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9000")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer ln.Close()
var num int

for {

    //Recibir un request
    conn, err := ln.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = binary.Read(conn, binary.LittleEndian, &num)

    io.WriteString(conn, fmt.Sprintf("I'm the server, the number I received is: ", num))

    conn.Close()
}
}
```

My server is sending back the message, but apparently its receiving a 0 instead of the number input by the user. It seems like this should be a simple thing to do but I can't figure it out.

Im not sure if I'm trying the correct implementation to do this. Is there a better way? And if not, why is my server not receiving the int properly?

Answer (score 2):

Always handle errors.

The call `binary.Read(conn, binary.LittleEndian, &num)` and `binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, num1)` return an error stating that `int`s are not supported.

The encoding/binary package works with fixed sized numbers ([doc](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#pkg-overview)). The size of an `int` is not fixed size because the size is platform dependent.

Declare`num1` in the client and `num` in the server to use fixed sized types.  For example, change both declarations to `int32`.

Add a format verb to the Sprintf call. I add %v here:

```
io.WriteString(conn, fmt.Sprintf("I'm the server, the number I received is: %v", num))
```

[Example modified to run on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4jYedsyAtA_t).

Comment: Thank you! Is this the common way to send data to a TCP server or is there a better way?

Comment: @samuel-amg Binary encoding is a common way to send data over TCP.